# jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

It seems as though as if some drivers interchangeably use:

- jdbcUrl
- jdbc-url
- url

StackTrack:

```
jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:954)   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109)  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35) at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)   at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:545)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:278)  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:262)  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:424)   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:173)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:401)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take note of the `jdbc-url` in the application.properties:

```
############# Legacy Datasource ################
spring.datasource.name=legacyDS
spring.datasource.username=db2inst1
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/testdb
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbcUrl=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8

###################  Hibernate Settings ###################
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```